# NP-COMPLETE:Why say "reduction algorithm computes reduction function"?

Tags: np-complete, complexity-classes

In Chap 34.3 *NP-completeness and reducibility* of the  book, *Introduction to Algorithm(3rd Edition)*, the author states(the original text):

We call the function *f* the ***reduction function***, and a polynomial-time algorithm *F* that computes *f* is a ***reduction algorithm***.

In my mind, function should be a machine dependent implementation(a set of instructions) of the algorithm. Why does he say *algorithm* computes *function*?

Comment: Because a *function* is the abstract mathematical thingy that an *algorithm* computes. Do not confuse this with "functions" in programming languages, which are more like algorithms than mathematical functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *function* is a mapping from elements in the domain to elements in the range. Here is an example of a function: $f(n) = n!$. If you want a machine to compute $f(n)$ given $n$, you need an algorithm, for example: given $n$, multiply together all the numbers from $1$ to $n$. There can be other algorithms for computing $f$. The function exists without reference to a machine. In fact, some functions (such as the halting function) cannot be computed by any algorithm.

You might be confusing the mathematical meaning of the term *function* with its meaning in programming languages, which is what you describe.